# PayPal IPN returning item_number empty

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

When I send cart details to paypal on checkout I include `item_numberX` for each item(i.e. `&item_number1=4`). When I recieve PayPals response all `item_number` fields are empty.

I can't figure out why this is happening. I need the item numbers in order to process the order.

Has anyone run into this, or know how I can fix it?

I am sending the order as ?cmd=_cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query item numbers should be written as `item_number_1` then the returned key is `item_number1`